# error using gcp cloud build to create dockerfile

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to build a `dockerfile` using google cloud platform\cloud build and the quickstart [guide](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker?hl=en_US&_ga=2.48650918.-1696395913.1540776674). I enter the steps in google shell but get the error

`-bash: FROM: command not found`

on the command `FROM alpine` (Preparing source files, step 2).

I must be making a basic mistake, I assume cloud build can create a dockerfile, and is there a command that needs to be entered before the `FROM alpine` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a file named `Dockerfile` with an editor such as `vi`. Then enter the commands into the file and save.

You tried to enter the Dockerfile statements into your shell.

Comment: thanks John. 
I've created the file but when I enter the command ``chmod +x quickstart.sh`` from a windows terminal in the folder where the file is saved, I get another error ``"chmod" is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.``

Comment: How did you get Powershell into your gcloud shell?

Comment: I didn't open Powershell in the gcloud shell, just opened it on its own. I've now created the files using Notepad++, installed linux/bash on windows ``(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzgwDbe7foQ)`` and continuing to work through the quickstart guide

Comment: John when executing this command     ``gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/[PROJECT_ID]/quickstart-image .`` I get an error ``gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated``. 

I created the Dockerfile and quickstart.sh files using Notepad++, is this the correct method?

Comment: @Zeus - Open a new question and I will help you. Long comment threads are frowned upon at StackOverflow. Let me know the question URL here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184002/discussion-between-zeus-and-john-hanley).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53405349/docker-file-error-gzip-stdin-invalid-compressed-data-crc-error