# docker file error gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--crc error

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

I'm learning how to used Docker and gcp using this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker?hl=en_US&_ga=2.48650918.-1696395913.1540776674), but have an error I can't fix. There are two files in the folder, `Dockerfile.txt` and `quickstart.sh`.

The Dockerfile has been created using Notepad++ and saved as a Dockerfile.txt file. When I run the command

`gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/[PROJECT_ID]/quickstart-image .`

I get an error

```
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--crc error
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--length error
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
ERROR
ERROR: fetching gcs source: unpacking tarball: exit status 2
```

I think this is caused by the Dockerfile format, should it be a bash file? I've recreated the file several times to make sure its not corrupted.

These are the files in the directory:

```
hugh@Hugh_Laptop:/mnt/d/temp$ ls -l
total 0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hugh hugh 55 Nov 21 15:05 Dockerfile.bash
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hugh hugh 51 Nov 21 13:38 quickstart.sh
```

Comment: What files are in the directory `.` (current directory)? Execute `ls -l' and add the output to your question.

Comment: What program did you create your text files with?

Comment: both files created with Notepad++

Comment: What selection in Notepad++ for "Save as type" when you saved the files?

Comment: I saved it as a normal .txt file

Comment: saving as Dockerfile.bash results in a different error message ``BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: exit status 1``

Comment: What files are in the directory . (current directory)? Execute `ls -l' and add the output to your question.

Comment: The name of the file must be Dockerfile, nothing else.

Comment: If you are on Windows, use `dir` and post that output (all of it).

Comment: see edited question with directory output using ubuntu

Comment: What happens when you run this command: `docker build -t example .` Don't forget the dot at the end.

Comment: Are you low on disk space in any of the mounted partitions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184003/discussion-between-zeus-and-john-hanley).

Comment: no plenty of disk space, running ``build -t example`` results in ``Command 'docker' not found, but can be installed with sudo apt install docker.io`` but running cmd results in ``unable to locate package docker.io``

Comment: A correctly setup development system is the first and most important step. Start over, get docker installed and running correctly, your tools, etc. I am stopping for the night. Make sure you post the solution as I am very curious.

Answer (score 1):

You most probably don't have python2 installed or set as default for /bin/python.

Install python2 and try again.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the extension of the `Dockerfile` is the cause of the issue.

I suggest to create a new `Dockerfile` without the `any` extension.